# how to generate animations and "button animations" like this?

Tags: jquery, animation

On
http://demo.thbthemes.com/blaine/?fixed

they have this very neat animation when you hover on a button, it gets a ->
Also the intro text animates a little on page load.

Any thought on how to reproduce these cleany with a animation library?
The html source is a mess so hard to figure out from there

It seems to use transition for the animation and adds a fontaswsome icon with css content directive pretty awsome, havent been able to find any information on this anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS animations/transitions, and pseudo-classes like `before` or `after` to store the arrow.

If you put `transition: all 0.15s ease-out;` it will animate the `:hover` state (in this example), I recommend you study CSS transitions.

Also you may need to add vendor specific prefixes (like `-moz-` or `-webkit-`) so that it works in browser versions that may not support it yet.

(If you study the source it will show you that it is done with css transitions, just pick some of it and make your examples).

Here's something to get you started (hover the "view" link in the code snippet):

```css
.thb-read-more {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 70px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  line-height: 1;
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
}
.thb-read-more:hover {
  margin-left: -4px;
}
.thb-read-more::after {
  content: "arrow";
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  width: 40px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
}
.thb-read-more:hover::after {
  content: "arrow";
  opacity: 1;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<a class="thb-read-more" href="#" rel="permalink">View</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for the writeup, very informative. Hard to find the exact solution if you don't know the terms technical implementation. I managed to figure it out myself in the end also looking at the code long enough.